# Any dangers of splitting the output of a universal laptop charger?

Tags: charger

I am looking at a 90W laptop charger and I would like to charger a laptop (65W) and a phone (15W) with it. The laptop charger has a 5.5mm / 2.5mm plug, one female to two male splitters are widely available, then I could use one of the male plugs with another plug converter for my laptop and with yet another to feed a Dell accessory which takes a barrel input and provides USB C power.

The question is, is this pile of plugs dangerous to the laptop or the charger?

Comment: From what I've seen most laptop charger units are just DC power supplies at a given voltage and current rating. ie: There's no feedback from the laptop. So (in theory) there shouldn't be an issue as long as you don't mess up the postive and negatives!

Comment: No problem with unbalanced loads and whatnot?

Comment: What about the voltage? Doesn't laptop charger usually comes with strange medium voltages? Like 17 V? I've never seen a laptop charger that delivers 5 V, which is what USB use. Having an "unbalanced load" doesn't matter at all. It's like you've got a water hose and you make two holes in it, one large and one small. The water will still flow all fine and dandy, the larger hole will receive more water, smaller hole smaller amount of water. Nothing weird about that.

Comment: This takes http://www.dell.com/en-us/work/shop/dell-adapter-45mm-barrel-to-usb-c/apd/470-acfg/pc-accessories 20V and the laptop charger is 20V too.

Comment: Ah I misread, I thought you would just hook up an USB connector to the terminals of the laptop charger. Well if you've got that item from dell then I can't see a problem.

Comment: Mine is a Dell and is...19.5V. There won't be a problem with different loads as far as the supply is concerned as long as the total load isn't too high.

One of my Dells has a feature in the BIOS which allows the USB ports to stay powered when the laptop is off - you might have that too if you are trying to charge your phone with the laptop off.